# Dest folder in dynamic files lookup

Tags: gruntjs

Consider following directory structure and files lookup:

static/
.. stylus/
.. css/

```
files: [
    {
        expand: true,
        cwd: 'static/',
        src: ['**/*.styl'],
        dest: 'css/',
        ext: '.css',
    },
],
```

What I wanted to do is to grab all *[*.styl]* files in `stylus/` dir, compile each of them into CSS and put result files into `css/` directory. But my pattern makes compiled files live in `static/stylus/css/` dir. How can I workaround this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
files: [
  {
    expand: true,

    // enable flatten if you want all files put into a single folder
    flatten: true,

    // specify the portion of the src folder you dont want to appear in the dest
    cwd: 'static/stylus/',

    src: ['**/*.styl'],
    dest: 'css/',
    ext: '.css',
  },
],
```